# How to backup DDMS (Android Device Monitor) filters on a Mac

Tags: android, macos, logcat, ddms

I have had some nice logcat "Saved Filters" setup in DDMS, but after having my machine restored without time machine, I now realized that I don't have the lovely filters I had before.

So now I'm trying to find out where DDMS saves these filters so I can write down what to backup and where to restore it from in the future.

Anyone has any ideas where these filters are saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. 
Apparently it's sitting right there in the same config folder for ddms: `~/.android/monitor-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs`